# How to use fadeOut jQuery property with Javascript Text Snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ <- fadeOut api

I'm trying to learn Javascript and I've been playing with a snippet I found on Codepen.

I'm having trouble trying to get the random text array snippet to have the text fadeOut when it transitions away to another text object. Right now, the array cycles through  and randomly selects a string from the array using the Math.Random function (5*1) and it fades in each time a new text object loads in, however I want it to fade out and I don't think I'm utilizing the .fadeOut property properly. How can I get it so that the text fadesOut, so the text does fadeIn fadeOut, instead of fadeIn, insta kill?

```
var textTimer;
var inTransition = false;

startTimer();

function startTimer() {
clearTimeout(textTimer);
textTimer = setTimeout(changeTitle, 3500);
}


changeTitle();
var titleNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
function changeTitle() {
var titleArray = [
    "Test1",
    "Test2",
    "Test3",
    "Test4",
    "Test5"
];
var tempTitleLength = titleArray.length - 1;

if (inTransition == false) {
    inTransition = true;
    titleNumber++;
    if (titleNumber > tempTitleLength){
        titleNumber = 0
    }
    $('.text').html(''); 
    $('.text').css({opacity: '0'});
    $('.text').html(titleArray[titleNumber]);
    $('.text').fadeOut(); 
    $('.text').stop().delay(0).animate({
        opacity: 1
        }, 1500, function() {
            inTransition = false;
            startTimer.()
        });
}
```

}

Thanks! :D

The HTML is pretty straight forward

```
 <div class="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems:

```
$('.text').html(''); 
$('.text').css({opacity: '0'});
$('.text').html(titleArray[titleNumber]);
```

You are already removing the text in html('') without fading out,
setting css opacity to 0 without any delay, setting html new text without any animation.

There is a syntax error also `startTimer.()` I guess is typo.

Remove first 2 lines and set new text after fade out is done.

You also need to wait for fadeOut to finish before doing fadeIn.
So, sequence: fadeOut, set new text, fadeIn.
Like this:

```
    $('.text').fadeOut(1500, function () {
        $('.text').html(titleArray[titleNumber]);
        $('.text').fadeIn(1500, function () {
            inTransition = false;
            startTimer()
        });
    });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dzyzw/

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! I'm new to Javascript so I'm still trying to understand the syntax. Do you know of any good books/resources I should look at?

Comment: you can find plenty of resources on net.. just google fore javascript tutorial. A good place to start with could be http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: Cool, thanks. I use w3 a lot and I'm taking classes at Treehouse and CodeSchool/CodeAcademy.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in your code:  you have `startTimer.()` should be `startTimer()` and you did not close your `startTimer` function with a `}`.  I corrected this for you and set up a sample JSFiddle for you review.  Seems to be working otherwise.

Here is the sample JSFiddle:  [CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7wztd/)

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to delete the startTimer. when I pasted my code in. I was playing around with .delay. Thanks for catching that and taking your time to help me :P

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think you're going for--

1. Set initial text.
2. Fade out your text.
3. Change the text.
4. Fade in the new text.
5. Wait a while, then return to step 2.

I would drop all the transition flags and use the optional callback functions that are fired when fadeOut and fadeIn complete to move from step to step, e.g.

```
$('.text').fadeOut(1000, function() {
   $('.text').html(get_next_word());
   $('.text').fadeIn(500);
});
```

Just fire that off on a timer that is 1500 milliseconds + the time you want the text to be fully visible.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try implementing this. Do I just remove the whole if block, when you say remove all the transition flags?